# How to configure Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql in XML configuration?

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework-core

I am trying to set up Entity Framework Core, with a Pomelo provider, in a .NET Framework (4.6.2) project. At runtime I get an error message

> The Entity Framework provider type 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql, Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySqlConnector' could not be loaded.

I am just guessing at the "invariantName" to use.  According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/config-file#ef-database-providers-ef6-onwards),

> invariantName identifies the core ADO.NET provider that this EF provider targets

I am also uncertain what class within the DLL is the actual data provider.

Here is configuration in Web.config at the moment:

```
<entityFramework>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    <provider invariantName="MySqlConnector" type="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql, Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" />
  </providers>
```

I've been unable to find documentation for setup in XML config files among the Pomelo pages. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: EF Core does not need such configuration section (`<entityFramework>` is for EF6). See [Connection Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings).

Comment: Thanks, Ivan.  But I'm still unclear on how to specify the entity framework provider.  In the application I'm modifying, the connection string is not read from Web.config, but assembled and passed as a constructor argument to DbContext.  Not sure how I can modify DbContext to specify a particular provider.

Comment: You don't need to. In EF Core db context is configured fluently - `UseSql`, `UseMySql` etc. It's up to you to call the correct `Use` method.

Comment: Probably this will help - [Configuring a DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbContext)

Comment: Thanks, Ivan. This helped me resolve that particular problem. I'm making a new question for a separate issue.

Comment: @Mike Kantor Did you manage to use Pomelo with the .NET (not Core) Application? I am asking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57850681/can-i-use-pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql-with-net-framework-4-x)

Comment: There is no any help page for .Net Framework Version with standard Version of `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql`, did you use it in .Net Framework 461+, using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/3.2.7