# Can I use Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql with .NET Framework 4.x?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I want to change my stack from Oracle's `Connector/NET` and `MySql.Data.Entity` to [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector) and [Pomelo EF Provider](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql).

`Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` is meant for .NET Core all right. But can I use it for good old .NET Projects? I do not find help at Pomelo's GitHub pages, but [How to configure Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql in XML configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57614123/how-to-configure-pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql-in-xml-configuration) and [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySQL DBContext throwing "Unqualified data type char" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662470/pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql-dbcontext-throwing-unqualified-data-type-char) suggest so.

I'd rather know beforehand and not try for days and finally fail.

Comment: The problem isn't .NET Core vs .NET Framework. It's EF vs EF Core. The two ORMs are very different. You can use EF Core in .NET Framework projects. If you don't use EF Core, you can't use any libraries built for it

Comment: BTW you can [use EF 6.3 in .NET Core 3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-3-0-preview-9-and-entity-framework-6-3-preview-9/) nowadays.

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos! This makes it quite clear. I will dive into EF Core now and I am quite sure it will satisfy my needs. Until now, I was only working with EF. What a pity that Model generation is not so straightforward and visual with EF Core - but it works and that is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pomelo/MySqlConnector solution can indeed be used with .NET Framework. As P. Kanavos says, the hard part is having to switch to EF Core. That also works with .NET Framework, but is significantly different from EF 6.x. If your use of EF is straightforward, the change should not be overly difficult. In my application, though, the design was heavily dependent on EF6 functionality that is not present in EF Core. (Specifically, chained inclusions of linked entities, including through collections.)  Also, we were composing expressions that represented the queries (with inclusions) in one class, and passing those through another class into the repository. That flow doesn't work nicely with EF Core's fluent composition of queries.

In the end, we wound up moving our database to MS SQL Server instead. But for a more conventional use of Entity Framework, it is feasible to switch to EF Core + Pomelo + MySqlConnector.

Comment: Thank you for following my call :) These were two hard hours but I managed to get everything into my project and scaffold my testing database in EF core with Pomelo. Now I'll have to look deeper in EF core, I'm afraid. I will definitely use it for new projects. I hope that I don't have to switch old projects, though.

Comment: Is there any sample to use `Pomelo.Entityframework.Core` standard version with Entityframework 6 in .Net Framework 472 by https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/3.2.7